# Android: Need to place a 3D object in AR in surrounding space without surface detection

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I feel the documentation and the tutorials to the ArCore are not enough and I need to know how I can place an anchor in mid air without the need for surface detection. Most of the source code available on AR core seems to deal with placing objects after surface detection.
I need to know how I can get a Session object, and place an anchor in the mid air as soon as the app opens. I'm currently using Sceneform on top of ARCore

Am I the only one to feel that the documentation available for ARCore is not enough?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this Github issue: [Can i place a anchor of the object in air instead of plane in ar-core android?](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/110)

This example from the Github issue places an anchor straight in front of the camera 1m away:

```
mAnchors.add(session.createAnchor(
frame.getCamera().getDisplayOrientedPose()
    .compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -1f))
    .extractTranslation()))
```

In the [create Anchor documentation](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Session#createAnchor(com.google.ar.core.Pose)) you see, that you only need a pose for creating an anchor.

Comment: How can I get a session and a frame object?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan don't get me wrong but you could at least to take a look on some basic examples. You`ll find there answer on the question about getting session and frame

Comment: @Fixus Thanks, I've actually tried it, but doesn't work! https://i.imgur.com/au6te3F.jpg I'm new to this and i don't even understand how to avoid using the ARfragment's click listener.

Comment: Thanks dude this helped a lot, had moved object with this, 
                                            Pose pose = anchor.getPose();          Pose newPose = pose.compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0.1f, 0f, 0f))
                                                    .extractTranslation();   
                     Anchor newAnchorToMove = mSession.createAnchor(newPose);